# ClamAV: MonoPosixHelper-x86_64.dll: Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193 FOUND - Is this a false positive?

Tags: wine, clamav

I did a full scan `clamscan -r` and `clamscan -r --bell -i /` of my machine using ClamAV and it found 1 "infected" file:

```
/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/windows/mono/mono-2.0/bin/MonoPosixHelper-x86_64.dll: Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193 FOUND
```

Is this a false positive? Should I just leave it be? It's only detected by ClamAV, according to virustotal.com.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virus is a Windows Machine Virus. This virus in no way will affect your Linux Machine. However, this will affect a Windows machine if you copy it to that. It is a part of the program `mono`. If you trust the application then it may be a false positive. In either case, you can keep it on your machine until and unless you aim to copy it to windows. In that case scan the file using a native windows anti virus before running `mono`.

Comment: I am thinking about the "trust" thing as it is found under `/USER/.wine`. I can delete the file, though.

Comment: Btw, What is mono? Who is the developer? Is the developer a reputed developer? Is mono being shown safe by virustotal.com. If all the answers are affirmative, then you must keep the file but take caution that you may be using the modded version of app.

Comment: As far as I know mono is sponsored by Microsoft [link](http://www.mono-project.com) but I am just skeptical of that file being on that folder. Virustotal shows only ClamAV which detects it.

Comment: If I had been in your place I would do like this. Rename the file by adding .bak after .dll. Then test the program, If it ran successfully without errors, I would delete the file. If it showed errors that showed it needed the file then I would rename it and remove .bak and accept the file as a false positive only if I had downloaded the program directly from the trusted site.

Comment: I reinstalled wine through the Software Center and found out that the file is there again in that folder so I am assuming it's a part of mono_2.0 so wine can run .NET 2.0 applications. I did your suggestion regarding naming the file with .bak but found no difference in using wine. I am now marking this as a false positive. I reported it to ClamAV already. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: If the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as selected answer.